# What software to use for DevSecOps pipeline?

Tags: automation, security, continuous-integration

I have a CD pipeline built in Jenkins that builds a Java project, packages the microservices as docker containers and uses terraform for provisioning on AWS. What are the plugins I should add to:

1. Do a static check of the containers for security flaws
2. Do dynamic checks of the webservices for security flaws
3. Do any other security checks that might be relevant

I already have Sonarqube set up for static code checking and I am aware of DefectDojo for keeping track of things. I also know of some OWASP tools, but trying to tie it all together in a best practice fashion.